# Как парсить используя библиотеку BeautifulSoup4 Python

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

```
<div class="soundTitle sc-clearfix sc-hyphenate sc-type-h2 sc-text-h4 streamContext m-interactive"><div class="soundTitle__titleContainer">
    <div class="soundTitle__playButton">
        <a role="button" href="" class="snippetUXPlayButton sc-button-play playButton sc-button sc-button-xlarge" tabindex="0" title="Play" draggable="true">Play</a>
    </div>

  <div class="soundTitle__usernameTitleContainer">
      <div class="sc-type-light sc-text-secondary sc-text-h4 soundTitle__secondary">
        <a href="/gracedaviesofficial" class="soundTitle__username sc-link-secondary
             sc-link-light">
          <span class="soundTitle__usernameText">
              Grace Davies
          </span>
        </a>
              </div>
        <a class="sc-link-primary soundTitle__title sc-link-dark sc-text-h4" href="/gracedaviesofficial/hello-adele">
            <span class="">Hello - Adele</span>
        </a>
  </div>
  <div class="soundTitle__additionalContainer sc-ml-1.5x">
      <div class="soundTitle__uploadTime sc-mb-0.5x">
        <time class="relativeTime" title="Posted on 26 October 2015" datetime="2015-10-26T14:51:09.000Z"><span class="sc-visuallyhidden">Posted 6 years ago</span><span aria-hidden="true">6 years ago</span></time>
      </div>
      <div class="soundTitle__tagContainer">
          <span class="sc-snippet-badge sc-selection-disabled sc-snippet-badge-medium sc-snippet-badge-grey sc-hidden"></span>
          <span class="sc-snippet-badge sc-selection-disabled sc-snippet-badge-small sc-snippet-badge-grey sc-hidden"></span>
          <a class="sc-tag soundTitle__tag sc-tag-small" href="/tags/hello"><span class="sc-truncate sc-tagContent">hello</span></a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Как мне получить `span` с названием песни,  и `href` из тега `<a>`, в который вложен этот `span`.

Пробовал использовать `find_all('a', attrs={'название класса':'значение класса'}[0].get('href')`, но получил ошибку `index out of range`. То есть, элемент не нашелся

`Span` тоже не знаю как получить.
Класса у него нету

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
a = soup.find('div' , {'class' : 'soundTitle__usernameTitleContainer'}).find_all('a')
for item in a:
    href = item['href']
    title = item.find('span').text
```

Ошибка 'index out of range' говорит о том, что в вашем списке нет элемента с таким индексом.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="soundTitle sc-clearfix sc-hyphenate sc-type-h2 sc-text-h4 streamContext m-interactive">
    <div class="soundTitle__titleContainer">
        <div class="soundTitle__playButton">
            <a role="button" href="" 
                class="snippetUXPlayButton sc-button-play playButton sc-button sc-button-xlarge" 
                tabindex="0" title="Play" draggable="true">Play</a>
        </div>

        <div class="soundTitle__usernameTitleContainer">
            <div class="sc-type-light sc-text-secondary sc-text-h4 soundTitle__secondary">
                <a href="/gracedaviesofficial" class="soundTitle__username sc-link-secondary sc-link-light">
                    <span class="soundTitle__usernameText">
                        Grace Davies
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <a class="sc-link-primary soundTitle__title sc-link-dark sc-text-h4" href="/gracedaviesofficial/hello-adele">
                <span class="">Hello - Adele</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="soundTitle__additionalContainer sc-ml-1.5x">
            <div class="soundTitle__uploadTime sc-mb-0.5x">
                <time class="relativeTime" title="Posted on 26 October 2015" datetime="2015-10-26T14:51:09.000Z">
                    <span class="sc-visuallyhidden">Posted 6 years ago</span><span aria-hidden="true">6 years ago</span>
                </time>
            </div>
            <div class="soundTitle__tagContainer">
                <span class="sc-snippet-badge sc-selection-disabled sc-snippet-badge-medium sc-snippet-badge-grey sc-hidden"></span>
                <span class="sc-snippet-badge sc-selection-disabled sc-snippet-badge-small sc-snippet-badge-grey sc-hidden"></span>
                <a class="sc-tag soundTitle__tag sc-tag-small" href="/tags/hello">
                    <span class="sc-truncate sc-tagContent">hello</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Находим тег <a> с классом 'soundTitle__title'
a_tag = soup.find('a', class_='soundTitle__title')

# Извлекаем текст из вложенного тега <span>
span_text = a_tag.span.get_text(strip=True)

# Получаем значение атрибута href из тега <a>
href_value = a_tag.get('href')

print(f"Название песни: {span_text}")
print(f"Ссылка (href): {href_value}")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]